# Unimplemented derived function in CRTP

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, abstract, crtp

I'm working on making a wrapper to be able to port future code easily to different backend rendering engines. We are currently working in GDI. Currently I am implementing virtual functions on an abstract backend, but I'd like to change that to CRTP since the backend should be known at compile time.

Unfortunately one hiccup I've experienced with CRTP (first time using) is that I must implement all details of derived functions. In contrast, the abstract implementation does not require fully implemented derived children. To demonstrate consider this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct AbstractBackend
{
  virtual ~AbstractBackend() = 0;

  virtual void foo()
  {
    throw "implementation missing: failed to override in derived class";
  }

  virtual void bar()
  {
    throw "implementation missing: failed to override in derived class";
  }
};

AbstractBackend::~AbstractBackend() {}

struct ConcreteBackendA : AbstractBackend
{
  int backendResource;

  ConcreteBackendA(int rsc) :
    backendResource(rsc)
  {}

  virtual void foo()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendA::foo!\n");
  }

  // ConcreteBackendA does not support "bar" feature
};

struct ConcreteBackendB : AbstractBackend
{
  HDC backendResource;

  ConcreteBackendB(HDC hdc) :
    backendResource(hdc)
  {}

  virtual void foo()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendB::foo!\n");
  }

  virtual void bar()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendB::bar!\n");
  }

};

struct FrontEnd
{
  AbstractBackend *backend;

  FrontEnd(int rsc) :
    backend(new ConcreteBackendA(rsc))
  {}

  FrontEnd(HDC hdc) :
    backend(new ConcreteBackendB(hdc))
  {}

  ~FrontEnd()
  {
    delete backend;
  }

  void foo()
  {
    backend->foo();
  }

  void bar()
  {
    backend->bar();
  }
};

int main()
{
  int rsc = 0;
  HDC hdc = 0;
  FrontEnd A(rsc);
  FrontEnd B(hdc);

  A.foo();
  A.bar(); // throws an error, A::bar is not a feature of this engine

  B.foo();
  B.bar();

  std::cin.get();
}
```

In this example, the AbstractBackend supports two features, foo & bar. The ConcreteBackendA only supports foo, bar is a function that it cannot support (maybe something like Draw3dText), but that's ok. The user can catch the exceptions and move on. One small drawback is the usage of virtual functions. I'd like to entertain the thought of using CRTP like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class Derived>
struct AbstractBackend
{
  virtual ~AbstractBackend() = 0;

  void foo()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
  }

  void bar()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
  }
};

template <class Derived>
AbstractBackend<Derived>::~AbstractBackend() {}

struct ConcreteBackendA : AbstractBackend<ConcreteBackendA>
{
  int backendResource;

  ConcreteBackendA(int rsc) :
    backendResource(rsc)
  {}

  void foo()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendA::foo!\n");
  }

  // ConcreteBackendA does not support "bar" feature
};

struct ConcreteBackendB : AbstractBackend<ConcreteBackendB>
{
  HDC backendResource;

  ConcreteBackendB(HDC hdc) :
    backendResource(hdc)
  {}

  void foo()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendB::foo!\n");
  }

  void bar()
  {
    printf("executing ConcreteBackendB::bar!\n");
  }
};

template <class ConcreteBackend>
struct FrontEnd
{
  AbstractBackend<ConcreteBackend> *backend;

  FrontEnd(int rsc) :
    backend(new ConcreteBackendA(rsc))
  {}

  FrontEnd(HDC hdc) :
    backend(new ConcreteBackendB(hdc))
  {}

  ~FrontEnd()
  {
    delete backend;
  }

  void foo()
  {
    backend->foo();
  }

  void bar()
  {
    backend->bar();
  }
};

int main()
{
  int rsc = 0;
  HDC hdc = 0;
  FrontEnd<ConcreteBackendA> A(rsc);
  FrontEnd<ConcreteBackendB> B(hdc);

  A.foo();
  A.bar(); // no implementation: stack overflow

  B.foo();
  B.bar();

  std::cin.get();
}
```

The problem is that if a derived class fails to implemented a function from the AbstractBackend, then the AbstractBackend will call itself causing a stack overflow.

How can I replicated the behavior of the virtual abstract implementation with CRTP?

Comment: "*The user can catch the exceptions and move on.*" But it *really shouldn't*. Calling an unimplemented function is either OK or it is a programming logic error (ie: the caller did not check to see if it was implemented). And if it is a logic error, your program has a bug in it. Continuing on is not really a reasonable thing at that point.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see, that might be an error on my approach to exceptions. My thought was that if there were, lets say 2 functions, drawtext and draw3dtext, the user could try draw3dtext, and if it fails, then it will just drawtext.

Comment: @YSC sorry about that I tried to minimize the code as much as I could while still compiling.

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Exceptions are not known for particualrly fast performance. Using them in the middle of what is probably your render loop is a particularly bad idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas What about returning a boolean, then handling that? so what about something like: if(!frontEnd.Draw3dText(params)) frontEnd.DrawText(params);

Comment: Or you could just do `if(frontEnd.CanDo3DText()) frontEnd.Draw3dText(params)`. I don't know why you insist on combining the attempt to do a thing with doing the thing itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187757/discussion-between-michael-choi-and-nicol-bolas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class Derived>
struct AbstractBackend
{
  virtual ~AbstractBackend() = 0;

  void foo()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
  }

  void bar()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar_impl();
  }

  void foo_impl()
  {
    throw "implementation missing: failed to override in derived class";
  }

  void bar_impl()
  {
    throw "implementation missing: failed to override in derived class";
  }

};
```

now you can have a default implementation of `foo`/`bar`.

Derived classes override `foo_impl` instead of `foo`.

However, this particular use is a bad plan; you know at compile time if a given `AbstractBackend<D>` is implemented or not.

We are, after all, implementing compile-time "dynamic" dipatch; why not evaluate the error at compile time?

```
  void foo_impl() = delete;
  void bar_impl() = delete;
```

now, at the moment the dispatch is done in your code at compile time, you are given the error, instead of waiting until compile time.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to not go with this solution until I get an idea why my design could be bad, but it answers my question perfectly. In anycase, I like the idea of deleting the function. The compile time error is much more useful than a runtime failure.

Answer (score 2):

You are abusing Object Oriented Programming.

Semantically, `AbstractBackend` is an interface: a contract. If a class `Alice` inherits from `AbstractBackend`, then an `Alice` *is an* `AbstractBackend`. Not partially an `AbstractBackend`. Fully an `AbstractBackend`. This is the [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the L of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

If classes `Bob` and `Charlie` partially implement `AbstractBackend`, this means you really have *two contracts*: `Interface1` and `Interface2`:

- `Bob` implements (inherits) `Interface1`,
- `Charlie` implements (inherits) `Interface2`,
- `Alice` implements (inherits) `Interface1` *and* `Interface2`.

CRTP is usable again, your code smells good and fresh, life is enjoyable. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Hmm. I might get a lot of flak for this but my thought process was to mimic Java default interfaces. I realize that the introduction of default methods was for pragmatic, not philosophical reason; however, that is what I believe my use case is here as well, that is why I'd want to allow partial implementation. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Java doesn't have multiple inheritance. I understand you might be very familiar with Java and try to feel "at home" in C++ by doing this, but that's not an option. C++ is really _not_ Java.

Comment: Where did multiple inheritance come it? I just mean that if there is an abstract class (java interface), I'd like to supply default functions (java defender methods). To clarify, a concrete class would inherit from the abstract class and if the concrete class fails to implement all the functions, then it will fall back to its default implementation. This is what I'd like to do with CRTP instead of virtual functions.

Comment: So this is callbacks you need, maybe. Anyhow, your usage of OOP in C++ is flawed. **Inheritance is the strongest of  the relations two classes can have, don't misuse it** or it will bite you.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the warning. I'll talk to my senior developer to maybe get some better ideas going instead since it seems my implementation of an abstract rendering engine could be flawed. In any case though, I'd still like to know the answer to the original question if CRTP can support default operations without running into a stack overflow.

Comment: Hello @Yakk. I've never said that, I love CRTP!